# How to compare Date Column between a row value and next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table **without ID** column like this:

```
2016-01-14 11:14:00.000
2016-01-14 11:13:00.000
2016-01-14 11:12:00.000
2016-01-14 11:11:00.000
2016-01-14 11:10:00.000
2016-01-14 11:09:00.000
2016-01-14 11:08:00.000
2016-01-14 11:07:00.000
```

I want to select this with one more boolean column who return true if the previous row has 1 minute less then your "fathers" row, like the following example:

```
2016-01-14 11:14:00.000  |  true
2016-01-14 11:13:00.000  |  true
2016-01-14 11:12:00.000  |  false (because the previous row is 2 minutes less)
2016-01-14 11:10:00.000  |  true
2016-01-14 11:09:00.000  |  true
2016-01-14 11:08:00.000  |  false (because the previous row is 3 minutes less)
2016-01-14 11:05:00.000
```

Hope someone can help me! Thanks for now!

Comment: How do you determine the _previous row_, ordered by the `datetime` value?

Comment: Im ordering by desc the column Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery with `CASE` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DateColumn,
       IsPrevOneMinuteLess = 
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, 
                         (SELECT MAX(DateColumn) 
                          FROM dbo.TableName t2 
                          WHERE t2.DateColumn < t.DateColumn), 
                          DateColumn) = 1
       THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END                    
FROM dbo.TableName t
```

Comment: Perfect!<br> Just added a "(" in the begin of "SELECT MAX(DateColumn) 
                   FROM dbo.TableName t2 
                   WHERE t2.DateColumn < t.DateColumn )" and works fine! <br> Thanks so much!